# Change X11 window title after emacs started

Tags: emacs, elisp, x11

When I start emacs, I can use the --title= option to control the title of the x-window that holds the emacs application.  Is it possible to change the title after emacs starts from elisp?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
M-x set-frame-name NewName RET
```

and from elisp

```
(set-frame-name "NewName")
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: GNU EMACS 24.3.1 on cygwin multiwindow X11. (set-frame-parameter frame 'title arg) works.

Comment: That didn't work form me, either. I was also using 24.3.1, but on Windows. I tried Krazy Glews's suggetion without success, until reading his full answer bellow, then I figured out that, in my case, I just needed replace 'frame' with nil. So using (set-frame-parameter nil 'title "My desired title") did the trick for me

Answer (score 10):

I use

```
(setq frame-title-format "%b - emacs")
```

to include the current buffer name in the frame title.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: GNU EMACS 24.3.1 on cygwin multiwindow X11. (set-frame-parameter frame 'title arg) works.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me (GNU EMACS 24.3.1 on cygwin multiwindow X11):

```
 (set-frame-parameter frame 'title arg)
```

which I wrapped in an interactive function

```
(defun set-frame-title/ag (title &optional frame)
  "set frame TITLE of &optional FRAME defaults to (selected-frame)
aka C11 window titlebar name"
  (interactive "sframe title: ")
  (set-frame-parameter frame 'title title)
  )
```

Comment: Satisfies my immediate need: some day I will tweak my frame-title-format to optionally mix in a frame specific name in combination with what I already do ("emacs hostname display pid user")